# How to combine hive two hive queries with avg and max funtions?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have below table :

```
hive> desc flightdelays2;
OK
airline                 string                                      
air_id                  string                                      
source_airport          string                                      
delay                   int                                         
dest_airport            string                                      
dest_id                 int                                         
codeshare               string                                      
stops                   int                                         
equipment               string                                      
Time taken: 0.104 seconds, Fetched: 9 row(s)
```

I want to find maximum of average of delay for each airline.

I am able to do this using below 2 commands :

```
hive> create table max_delays as select airline as air_name,avg(delay) as avg_delay from flightdelays2 GROUP BY airline;
hive> select max(avg_delay) from max_delays
```

;

Is there a way to find this in single hive query without creating any additional table ?

Answer (score 0):

One method is a subquery:

```
select max(avg_delay)
from (select airline as air_name, avg(delay) as avg_delay
      from flightdelays2 
      group by airline
     ) a;
```

A simpler method actually let's you see the airline as well (well, one airline in the case of ties):

```
select airline as air_name, avg(delay) as avg_delay
from flightdelays2 
group by airline
order by avg_delay desc
limit 1
```